# Odoo 8 alternative to _constraints

Tags: python-2.7, constraints, openerp-7, odoo-8

I need an alternative to the `_constraints` in Openerp 7 for Odoo 8.

I have a new field added to `res.partner` that I want to check for certain conditions before saving it.

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: What's wrong with `@api.constraints` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@api.constraints` decorator.

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('new_field')
def _check_description(self):
    if self.new_field < 0: # Test new_field
        raise ValidationError("new_field should be positive")
```